# Python: Printing nested classes

Tags: python, class, printing, nested

What's the best way to print the contents of a nested class? For example:

```
class Library():
    def __init__(self):
        self.shelves = []
        self.shelf = self.Shelf()

    class Shelf():
        def __init__(self):
            self.books = []


x = Library()
```

I know vars(x) works if the class is not nested. But if it is, I get something like:

```
{'shelf': <__main__.Shelf instance at 0x7f4bae723560>, 'shelves': []}
```

as the output. How do I get python to print it out as:

```
{'shelf': {'books': []}, 'shelves': []}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would recommend that you not nest classes. There isn't really any reason to do so.

Second, you're seeing exactly what you're supposed to: the value for the `shelf` variable is a `Shelf` object, and you haven't defined any special appearance (or "reproduction") for it. Since `vars` is not recursive, you see the default appearance with a memory location.

If you want to see the contents of a `vars()` call on a `Shelf` object when printing the `Shelf` object, you can define a `__repr__` method for `Shelf` that calls `vars()` on itself:

```
class Library():
    def __init__(self):
        self.shelves = []
        self.shelf = self.Shelf()
    class Shelf():
        def __init__(self):
            self.books = []
        def __repr__(self):
            return str(vars(self))
```

```
>>> x = Library()
>>> vars(x)
{'shelf': {'books': []}, 'shelves': []}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I use nested classes to breakdown what each class if it has parameters that I need to build upon.

Answer (score 6):

You are aiming to have a string version of your objects.  Python knows two methods for this: `__repr__()` and `__str__()`.  The first is meant to be a string which, if interpreted as Python source, would re-generate the thing it represents.  If you just call `vars(x)` you receive a `dict` of all fields in the given `x`.  Most means to output this `dict` (and probably also yours) make it call the `__repr__()` function of each of its contents.  That's why you see that ugly string `<__main__.Shelf instance at 0x7f4bae723560>` because that's the `__repr__()` of your `Shelf` object.

I propose to implement it and thus override the standard implementation.  You will have to do that in `Shelf`:

```
class Library():
    def __init__(self):
        self.shelves = []
        self.shelf = self.Shelf()

    class Shelf():
        def __init__(self):
            self.books = []
        def __repr__(self):
            return repr(vars(self))

x = Library()
```

And while you're at it, you could do the same in your `Library` as well; then typing `x` alone (i. e. instead of `vars(x)`) would also give the nice output:

```
class Library():
    def __init__(self):
        self.shelves = []
        self.shelf = self.Shelf()
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(vars(self))

    class Shelf():
        def __init__(self):
            self.books = []
        def __repr__(self):
            return repr(vars(self))

x = Library()
```

And of course you can refactor that out and put that aspect into a base class:

```
class Representer(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(vars(self))

class Library(Representer):
    def __init__(self):
        self.shelves = []
        self.shelf = self.Shelf()

    class Shelf(Representer):
        def __init__(self):
            self.books = []

x = Library()
```

Comment: This is a big help in easily printing out what I need, thanks.